# Running of team city build in the loop

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, build-chain

I have build configuration in TeamCity with automated tests. I want to run this build configuration in the loop: when one build was finished, new build is started. I can not configure 'Finish Build Trigger', because it is necessary to create snapshot dependencies for it, but I want to run tests for the latest version of code each time. How I can configure such loop?

Answer (score 3):

From your question:

> I can not configure 'Finish Build Trigger', because it is ***necessary*** to
>   create snapshot dependencies for it

Actually, it is NOT *nescesary* to have a snapshot dependency for a "Finish Build Trigger". You will, however, get a warning saying that "*There is not snapshot dependency on the selected build configuration*", but that will not keep you from triggering on a selected build.

**From [Teamcity Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger):**

> If there is no snapshot dependency, the following limitations exist:
>
> - it is likely that a build of the build configuration being triggered    will not have the same revisions as the finished build
>     even if both    configurations have the same VCS settings
> - if a build configuration with the Finish Build Trigger has an    artifact dependency on the last finished build of the build
>     configuration specified in the trigger settings, there is no
>     guarantee that artifacts of a build which caused build triggering
>     will be used, because, while the triggered build sits in the build
>     queue, another build may finish
> - the build triggered by the Finish Build Trigger will always be    triggered in the default branch even if the finished build has some
>     other branch

I do recommend to select the "*Trigger after successful build only*" checkbox since you are running unit tests.